# man -k [apropos options] regexp ... what does the "[apropos options]" mean?

Tags: linux, shell, manpage

I am a beginner of linux. I've been learning how to use `man`.
`man man`  shows

> man -k [apropos options] regexp ...

I know that how to use `man -k regexp....` but I don't understand  the format `[apropos options]`

I know this is an optional part,  but manpager doesn't describe how to use this part.
I wonder what this complete usage pattern means. What can I replace this part `[apropos options]` with.

Unfortunately,  I didn't find the answer on the Internet.   Please give me a specific example.

Comment: Read `man apropos`

Comment: I would assume that any of the options that `apropos` take could be used there and behave the same.

Comment: @CuriousMan is right, there's no further information about how to use `[apropos options]`. We can assume that any `apropos` option could be used to get the same results, but that's not what happens. Try this: `apropos -a output part file` (results in 'head' and 'tail' here) and `man -k -a output part file`